# htaccess Rewrite not working on LAMP server

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, lamp

I rencently installed [phpbrew](https://github.com/phpbrew/phpbrew) on my LAMP server (ubuntu), and it seems that I have a configuration problem since. I have two [symfony2](https://symfony.com/) applications and one [slim](https://www.slimframework.com/) application installed but I have redirection issues.

I can't acces my Symfony2 app using `localhost/my-app/` anymore, I have to use `localhost/my-app/web/app_dev.php/` to run the applications which is not normal.

My slim application is not working neither. I want to access `http://localhost/slimapp/admin/public/index.php` using the address : `http://localhost/slimapp/admin`
My routes are designed to be used like this :

```
http://localhost/slimapp/admin/login
http://localhost/slimapp/admin/user
http://localhost/slimapp/admin/user/update
etc...
```

in my admin folder (of my slim application : var/www/html/slimapp/admin/) , I have an .htaccess like this :

```
# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_URI} ^.+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(gif|jpe?g|png|js|css|swf|php|ico|txt|pdf|xml)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    IndexIgnore *.zip *.jpg *.gif
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    public/index.php    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) public/index.php/$1    [L]
 </IfModule>
```

Is my htaccess wrong or is it a config issue ?

If it is a config issue, how to identify the problem ?

Thanks

Comment: if you are using symphony2 did u refer to the symphony2 htaccess file? https://gist.github.com/ijy/6309892

Comment: The thing is that it was working fine before my phpbrew install. I tryed this htaccess file and it is not working neither. With the one you sent me, I have the list of all file/folders in my project displayed in the browser. With the one I had, I have a 404 erro when accessing localhost/mysymfony2project/